# Angular - Can't get updated value from service to component

Tags: angular

Can't get updated value from service to component. what is my mistake?

this is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  private text = 'one';
  
  getText() {
    return this.text;
  }
  
  modifyText(word: string) {
    this.text.concat(word)
  }
}
```

and this is my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  providers: [DataService],
  template: `
  <p>{{value}}</p>
  <p>{{changeText('two')}}</p> <!-- can't get any 'value'-->
  `,
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  value = '';
  
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.value = this.dataService.getText();
  }
  
  changeText(word: string) {
    this.dataService.modifyText(word);
  }
}
```

I do not want to use any `<input>` or `<button>`, I do not want to do it with any event. Do not want to use `rxjs`.

If possible please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wnat this to show modyfied value:

```
 <p>{{changeText('two')}}</p> <!-- can't get any 'value'-->
```

You need to add `return` statement in:

```
 modifyText(word: string) {
    return this.text.concat(word)
  }
```

and

```
changeText(word: string) {
    return this.dataService.modifyText(word);
  }
```

Comment: your suggestion works. Thanks! just remove "Answer above and also:" (because they do not work) and I will mark your answer as 'Answered'

Comment: Also as @nate-kumar said if you want to modify the value in the template try using pipes.

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to avoid using functions in the template unless linked to an event emission such as `(click)`. This is because Angular can not tell whether the contents of your function's return value have changed and so it constantly reruns it just in case leading to a worsened performance.

See this article for more explanation: https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

If you instead want to perform an operation enclosed in a function in the template, you should leverage [Angular's pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes). Pipe's are optimised pure functions which will only execute whenever the input value changes, specifically bypassing this need to constantly rerun the function

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dvbmpq?file=src%2Fdata.service.ts)

`modify-text.pipe.ts`

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'modifyText',
  standalone: true,
})
export class ModifyTextPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

    transform(text: string): string {
        return this.dataService.modifyText(text);
    }
}
```

`data.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  private text = 'one';
  
  getText(): string {
    return this.text;
  }
  
  modifyText(word: string): string {
    return this.text.concat(word);
  }
}
```

`parent.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  imports: [ModifyTextPipe],
  providers: [DataService],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <p>{{ value }}</p>
    <p>{{ 'two' | modifyText }}</p>
  `,
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  value = '';

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.value = this.dataService.getText();
  }

  changeText(word: string) {
    this.dataService.modifyText(word);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the changeText, you need to get the Value and assign it to this.value.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  providers: [DataService],
  template: `
  <p>{{value}}</p>
  <p>{{changeText('two')}}</p> <!-- can't get any 'value'-->
  `,
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  value = '';
  
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.value = this.dataService.getText();
  }
  
  changeText(word: string) {
    this.dataService.modifyText(word);
    // Again you need to set the value after the change
    this.value = this.dataService.getText();
  }
}
```

Comment: your suggestion does not works :(